# How to deselect "https://mail.google.com/ scope" in Credentials

Tags: google-api

I am lost in the user interface of Google developer console.
Created two scopes for google mail:

1. https://mail.google.com/
2. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send

Now I need to get rid of nr. 1 but cannot find anywhere in the developer console any user interface to allow me to deselect the "https://mail.google.com/ scope".

Below is the email From Google with what I am supposed to do:

Begin Quote

Dear Developer,

Thank you for your response.

To proceed with the verification process, please deselect the https://mail.google.com/ scope and update the request for scopes in the codebase of your app so that the scopes requested by your app match the scopes in your Console.

End Quote

In "Credentials > Oauth consent screen" I clicked on the "trash" icon to delete it. After refreshing the page was still there. 
In the "Add New Scope" list, is grayed out, so cannot deselect. What can I do?

Screenshot https://filebin.net/yg4g37xjmcu5bcxv/scope.png?t=v9jjj7g6

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, after deleting "https://mail.google.com/ scope", I submitted again for verification.
Now the scope I wanted to delete is gone and will go again through the verification process. What a mess!